# How to get a sprite to scale in Phaser

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm importing an image from a JSON spritesheet, which works okay. However, I want to get the sprite to scale once it is in the game. Using the code below, I get the error in console:

> Uncaught TypeError: plane.scale is not a function

```
    const config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    scene: {
        preload: preload,
        create: create
        }
    };

    const game = new Phaser.Game(config);

    function preload () {
        this.load.image('background', 'assets/1.jpg');
        this.load.multiatlas('aircraft', 'assets/texture.json', 'assets');
    }

    function create () {
        const background = this.add.image(800, 600, 'background');
        const plane = this.add.sprite(200, 200, 'aircraft', 'Glider2.png');
        plane.scale(0.1, 0.1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused, because the function `scale` does not exist *(`scale` is a property)*, you would need to use the function `setScale` *(link [to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.Sprite.html#setScale__anchor))*.

**The code should look like this:**

```
...
const plane = this.add.sprite(200, 200, 'aircraft', 'Glider2.png');
plane.setScale(0.1);
...
```

***btw:** if the *scale-value* should be the same value on the `x` and the `y` axis you can omit the second parameter.*

Comment: I found I could also use plane.scale = 0.1;